# "Cannot convert value to NodaTime.LocalDateTime"

Tags: c#, nodatime, .net-core-3.1

I am using .Net Core 3.1 as my framework.

I have this setup on my startup:

```
using NodaTime;
using NodaTime.Serialization.SystemTextJson;

services.AddControllers()
        .AddJsonOptions(options =>
        {
            var settings = options.JsonSerializerOptions;

            settings.AllowTrailingCommas = false;
            settings.ConfigureForNodaTime(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb);
            settings.WithIsoDateIntervalConverter();
            settings.WithIsoIntervalConverter();
        });
```

And this is my API model:

```
public class CreateDto
{
    public int Status { get; set; }

    public Guid ApprovedBy { get; set; }

    public LocalDateTime DateFrom { get; set; }

    public LocalDateTime DateTo { get; set; }
}
```

This is my Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody] CreateDto createEntity)
{
    var createdEntity = await _service.Create(createEntity);
    return Ok(createdEntity);
}
```

Everytime I use Postman with this JSON Body:

```
{
    "Status": 1,
    "ApprovedBy": "970a50c5-ae21-4f41-bea9-691f8c60224c",
    "DateFrom": "2020-04-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "DateTo": "2020-04-05T23:59:59.000Z"
}
```

I always gets this error:

```
{
    "errors": {
        "DateTo": [
            "Cannot convert value to NodaTime.LocalDateTime"
        ],
        "DateFrom": [
            "Cannot convert value to NodaTime.LocalDateTime"
        ]
    },
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "|4a836dd3-4ce779bc5503ac63."
}
```

Question: Am I missing something on my Startup Configuration? If not, what can I do to fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON doesn't represent `LocalDateTime` values - it represents `Instant` (or `OffsetDateTime`) values, due to the "Z" on the end.

So your options are:

- Change the type in your model to `Instant` or `OffsetDateTime`
- Change the data you're sending - just remove the 'Z' from the end of each string

Comment: I took your second option and it works! Man, I can't believe something so simple will fix this. This problem took me a lot of hours. Thank you very very much!